# I want to display background while scrolling down

Tags: javascript

I want to display some background under my menu using this code but it does not work. The background color should be displayed after scrolling down for 50 pixels. Could someone help me ? When I am creating function just for scrolling without height, It does work and add background but when i want to toggle it while in certein distance something is wrong.

Here is the code:

```js
window.onscroll = function() { load() };

function load() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        menu.classList.add('load');
    } else {
        menu.classList.remove('load');
    }
};
```

```css
nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

nav .menu-items a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}


nav .menu-items.open {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav .menu-items.scroll {
  height: 50px;
  background: #585858;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class="logo">
            logo
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="first-line"></div>
            <div class="second-line"></div>
            <div class="third-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#description">Description</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="log-in.html" target="_blank">Log-in</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: A very minor one, but instead of creating a new function, you could just have... `window.onscroll  = load`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
window.onscroll = function() { load() };

function load() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        //if you want color the navbar, put 'menu-items' instead 'text' under here
        document.getElementById("text").style.backgroundColor = 'blue';//or what you want
    } else {
        document.getElementById("text").style.backgroundColor = 'white';//or what you want
    }
};
```

```css
nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

nav .menu-items a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

nav .menu-items.open {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav .menu-items.scroll {
  height: 50px;
  background: #585858;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class="logo">
            logo
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="first-line"></div>
            <div class="second-line"></div>
            <div class="third-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='menu-items' class="menu-items">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#description">Description</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="log-in.html" target="_blank">Log-in</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
    <p id='text' style='position: relative; top: 100px'>Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa. Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa.<br /> Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa.<br /> Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.<br />Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa. Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
```

I added an **id menu-items** in the **div of the menu** and i modified the javascript file by putting that **after the scroll 50, the element with id text** (the text Lorem Ipsum) **changes the color** and **if the scroll is less than 50 it returns white**

Comment: It's always better to describe exactly **what** you've done, as well as provide an example. Otherwise people have to search through your answer to find what is different

Comment: There is no way to add class from css ? What if i want to style more than one property, do I have to write everything in js ?

Comment: If you want change 2 or more element you can do by adding a id and 'documenti.getElementById(id).style.whatyouwant = something. In css you can put a class and in js with toggleClass() add at every element you want